# Good way to switch AC/DC (Rectifier) in welder

Tags: current, switches, ac, transformer, dc

I am building a homemade welder out of microwave oven transformers.  I would like to have ideally an on off switch and then an AC/DC switch or just having one switch would work too.  AC 120V 60Hz comes in through the wall, gets transformed to high current lower voltage and the leads from that go to a bridge rectifier and that's the output (a little simplified).  I'd like a way to bypass the rectifier using a switch setup so that I could do AC and DC welding. I can't use a polarity like switch with the high current cause the switch will probably burn up or weld together.

Comment: I would be surprised if a microwave oven transformer used in reverse will survive the kind of current needed for welding for very long. It is not meant for this application (obviously). The secondary (your primary) will be made of thin wire and probably will go open circuit after not too long if you draw too much current from the other winding. Another issue is that a diode-based rectifier has some associated voltage drop. If your output from the transformer is less than a volt, it may not be possible to rectify it in this way.

Comment: I'm using 2 transformers in series to get about 80 amps and somewhere around 50v output.  You're right in saying they're not made for this and the duty cycle will be pretty short but that's OK by me and I realize it won't last long, I've already tripped the breaker many times.  With a higher voltage output The rectifier should work OK I hope.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess your best bet is a starter contactor for an automobile. You can get 100 amp units for less than 20 bucks, and you might do a lot better at a junkyard. They typically aren't rated for continuous duty, but I'll bet your welder isn't either.

You can get away with this because you aren't attempting to activate or deactivate the switch while current is flowing, and there isn't much voltage across your bridge.

You'd need to make a little 12 volt supply for the coil, but that shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can find a contactor rated for what I need and hopefully for the voltage...